# I am not confident about my answers

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

• Birkett: A hill in the Lake District National Park with a height of at least 1000ft.

• Nuttall: A hill in England or Wales with a height of at least 2000ft and at least 15m of prominence.

• Wainwright: A hill in the Lake District National Park appearing in Alfred Wainwright’s Pictorial Guide to the Lakeland Fells.
In the Lake District, there are 558 hills which meet at least one of these requirements.

• 541 of these hills are Birketts;

• 169 of these hills are Nuttalls;

• 214 of these hills are Wainwrights;

• 157 of these hills are both Birketts and Nuttalls;

• 209 of these hills are both Birketts and Wainwrights;

• 113 of these hills are Birketts, Nuttalls, and Wainwrights.
With the information provided and using sensible set theory notation and formulae, determine:

1. Whether there are any hills which are both Nuttalls and Wainwrights, but not Birketts;
2. How many hills meet exactly one of the classification requirements;
3. How many hills meet exactly two of the classification requirements?
   In each case, draw a Venn diagram with three sets to indicate the set we are interested in.
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlDmd.png

MY ANSWER

1. $\vert N\cap W\cap\neg B\vert =270−113=157$
2. $558=B+N+W−2×(B\cap N)−2×(B\cap W)−2×(N\cap W)+3×(B\cap N\cap W)$
3. Total hills meeting exactly two=$2×(B\cap N)+2×(B\cap W)+2×(N\cap W)−3×(B\cap N\cap W)=280$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This question is slightly hill-formulated.